# How to transfer values between Userforms in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'd like to use two userforms in Excel.
the first userform have two buttons.
The first button 'Go' can give number 1 to a, and go to the second userform.

```
Public a as Integer
Private Sub Go_Click()
UserForm2.Show
a = 1
End Sub
```

And another button 'Show' can show me the values of a and b.

```
Private Sub Show_Click()
Load UserForm2
Debug.Print a, b
End Sub
```

In the second userform, it can distribute 2 to b (and close the window of userform2).

```
Public b as Integer
Private Sub Back_Click()
Load UserForm1
b = 2
UserForm2.Hide
End Sub
```

I want when I click 'Show' in the first userform, it can show me both a and b (1 and 2). How could I correct my code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this code in `Userform1`:

```
Public a As Integer
Public frm As UserForm2

'Userform1 code.
Private Sub Go_Click()
    Set frm = New UserForm2
    a = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Show_Click()
    Debug.Print a, frm.b
    Set frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

And this in `userform2`:

```
Public b As Integer

'UserForm2 code
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    b = 2
End Sub
```

The 'Go_Click' in `Userform1` creates a new class instance of `Userform2` which will fire the `Userform_Initialise` event in `Userform2` and set a value to variable `b`.  You can then reference it from the `frm` variable in `Userform1`.

You can enter text into Userform2 and hide the form:
**Userform1 code:**

```
Public a As Integer
Public frm As UserForm2

'Userform1 code.
Private Sub Go_Click()
    Set frm = New UserForm2
    a = 1
    frm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Show_Click()
    Debug.Print a, frm.b, frm.TextBox1
    Set frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

**UserForm2 code:**

```
Public b As Integer

Private Sub btnClose_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

'UserForm2 code
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    b = 2
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried your code and it works well. And I have still a question about this. In the second userform, I want to use a boutton instead of initialise. Because in the second userform, the user will input some thing in the textbox, and I want to use them in the first userform. Is that possible? Or do you have some better ways?

Comment: And I've tried to add a new botton to close the userform2, but there is an error 402, says I should close the window in the first plan.

Comment: I've added code to take text from Userform2.  The close button hides the userform and `Userform1.commandbutton2` removes the `frm` from memory.