# Save variable from Hidden userform to another

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if it was possible to keep my integer n from this form once i Hide it to go to the other user form?

I need "n" as and index so that i can modify that specific row.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    Dim n As Integer
    
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            n = i + 2
        
        End If
    Next i
  
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This link may help: https://rubberduckvba.blog/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Sorry i meant hidden form

Comment: Found a question I answered years ago.  Maybe not the absolute correct way to do it, but think it worked - got a tick for it at any rate.  [How to transfer values between Userforms in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081175/how-to-transfer-values-between-userforms-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I made a public Integer k on a separate module and stored n in k

Module `functions`

```
public k as Integer
```

User form

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    Dim n As Integer
    
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            n = i + 2
        
        End If
    Next i
  functions.k = n
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a variable declared on one from using code that is on a different form, the variable needs to be declared as a public variable.  let's suppose that the code you showed in your question is on a form named "form1", change the code so that the variable named "n" is declared at the top of the form's code module with the keyword "Public" instead of "Dim" as follows:

```
Public n As Integer

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

  For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        n = i + 2
    
    End If
  Next i


End Sub
```

Now, if form1 is hidden, its variable named "n" can be accessed from a different form using the following code:

```
Private Sub button1_Click()

   Debug.Print form1.n

End Sub
```